# Swapping day and month using JavaScript or PHP

Tags: php, javascript, fullcalendar

I'm using the jQuery Fullcalendar plugin and noticed that it expects events to be in the format of `'mm-dd-yyyy'` but my event feed is `'dd-mm-yyyy'`.

Is there a simple way to convert this using JavaScript/PHP? As I am unable to change the format for the event feed. *And I've looked in the Fullcalendar docs and not seen any way to change the format for how fullcalendar uses dates... as this would be better.*

Here is an example of the code (uses WordPress custom types):

```
$('#training-calendar').fullCalendar({
    viewDisplay: function(view) {
        resizeCalendar();
    },
    windowResize: function(view) {
        resizeCalendar();
    },
    header: {
        left: 'title',
        center: '',
        right: 'today prev,next'
    },
    editable: false,
    events: [
        <?php $training_query = new WP_Query('post_type=training'); while ($training_query->have_posts()) : $training_query->the_post(); $id = get_the_ID(); ?>
        {
            title: '<?php the_title(); ?>',
            start: '<?php echo get_post_meta($id, 'startDate', true ); ?>',
            end: '<?php echo get_post_meta($id, 'endDate', true); ?>',
            allDay: true
        },
        <?php endwhile; ?>  
    ]
});
```

So the date would be for Jan 5th 2013 : `05-01-2013`

**Also I'm sure I remember Fullcalendar had issues with the months starting at 0, has this been changed in later releases?**

Comment: please share your code and we'll suggest the fix

Comment: Need to customize calendar code

Comment: you sure you want to convert date format in JavaScript. This could be done in PHP in your case.

Comment: @Ejay PHP would be fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
$d = date('m-d-Y', strtotime(get_post_meta($id, 'startDate', true )));
```

Comment: You might also want to look out for timezone offsets while working with dates(Not sure if wordpress handles it already). `Also I'm sure I remember Fullcalendar had issues with the months starting at 0, has this been changed in later releases?` and i'm not sure about this.